# Matrix PHP preference error on Pages module admin

Tags: matrix, pages, ee

Am updating an old EE site to a new server, I have had a few errors that seem strange that they worked on last server.

ee v2.7.1
matrix 2.5.8
pages 2.2

If I go to Addons > Modules > Pages
If I click on any of the pages links I get:
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Tools_model::get_upload_preferences() in /var/www/website/sys/expressionengine/third_party/matrix/celltypes/file.php on line 121

Anyone seen this as to where I would look to change the upload prefs or which thing might have a problem.

thanks

Note:

On the second site I am moving I get this msg in the dev log:
The system has detected an add-on that is using outdated code that may stop working or cause issues with the system. What does this mean?

Deprecated function get_upload_preferences() called in /var/www/website/sys/expressionengine/third_party/matrix/celltypes/file.php on line 121.
Deprecated since 2.2. Use File_upload_preferences_model::get_file_upload_preferences() instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running Matrix 2.5.8. In the [Matrix Changelog](http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/matrix/changelog.html) for Matrix 2.5.9 (released 5 months ago) is:

> Fixed a PHP error that could occur when a new File cell was saved for the first time

I suggest updating to the latest version (currently 2.5.10). In general, it's a good idea to update to the latest version of any software if you run into a PHP error, as these are often quickly caught and fixed by the developers.

Comment: Thank you @adrian, I think this server has a newer version of php as dont see why I should need to update all the extensions if it was working, but thanks for pointing it out